# @Before doesn't allow pointcut reference, why?

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I can do

```
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.learning.validation.Validate)")
    public void validatePointCut() {
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "validatePointCut()")
    public void validate(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    // some code
    }
```

but i cannot do

```
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.learning.validation.Validate)")
    public void validatePointCut() {
    }

    @Before(pointcut = "validatePointCut()")
    public void validate(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    // some code
    }
```

i have to do

```
    @Before("@annotation(com.learning.validation.Validate)")
    public void validate(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    // some code
    }
```

i was hopping to use @Before same as @AfterReturning,
i am using Spring Boot 3.x and Spring AOP
am i missing something or is this how it should work

Comment: Hello and welcome. I guess this is the correct syntax: `@Before("validatePointCut()")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that [`@Before`](https://github.com/eclipse-aspectj/aspectj/blob/master/runtime/src/main/java/org/aspectj/lang/annotation/Before.java#L28-L31) only knows the default parameter name `value`for the pointcut expression, while [`@AfterReturning`](https://github.com/eclipse-aspectj/aspectj/blob/master/runtime/src/main/java/org/aspectj/lang/annotation/AfterReturning.java#L28-L36) defines an additional alias `pointcut` for it.

I.e., for `@Before` you can write any of

- `@Before("validatePointCut()")`,
- `@Before(value = "validatePointCut()")`,

while for `@AfterReturning` you can write any of

- `@AfterReturning("validatePointCut()")`,
- `@AfterReturning(value = "validatePointCut()")`,
- `@AfterReturning(pointcut = "validatePointCut()")`.

I recommend you to learn how to use the features of your IDE to be able find out about the APIs you use right from the code editor, while typing your program.